# Are closures allocated memory when they are defined or first called?

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures

Are closures allocated memory when they are defined or first called?  For example, is the closure for the name `asHTML` allocated memory when the `HTMLElement` named `headerTitle` is instantiated, or on the next line when `asHTML()` is called. Furthermore, with classes a deinit implementation is provided.  Is there a similar feature for closures?

```
class HTMLElement {
    let name: String
    let text: String?
    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(self.text ?? "")</\(self.name)>"
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }
    deinit {print("\(name) is being deinitialized")}
}

var headerTitle: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "h1", text: "Welcome")
print(headerTitle!.asHTML())
headerTitle = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, a closure will need to be allocated at its definition site in order to capture variables used within the closure that are outside of the closure. However, the `lazy` keyword makes it so that the closure is not declared until its first use. From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

I'm assuming what you mean by *deinit* for closures mean to release any strong references to reference-semantic variables in your closure. Your example comes from Apple's own *The Swift Programming Guide (Swift 4)*. They explain that this example has a strong reference cycle, meaning the class instance holds a strong reference to the closure, and the closure has a strong reference to the instance. And nether are willing to release one another causing the instance to never be de-initialized. Here is Apple's visual:
[image]

If you read look further ahead in the chapter, they speak about defining a capture list to break the strong reference cycle.

```
lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
    [unowned self] in /*<-- Add self in the capture list, so the closure does not have a strong reference to the instance. */
    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}
```

[image]

Now when `headerTitle` is set to `nil`, the `deinit` print message will show.

Comment: I meant: is there a way I could execute code when the closure is being deallocated? for example a print statement that prints "closure is being deallocated."

Comment: To my knowledge, no. Closures aren't objects.

Comment: But they are allocated memory right? That is how I thought they can cause a retain cycle.  If they're allocated memory shouldn't there be a way to check the moment they are deallocated?

Comment: Swift handles memory deallocation automatically, including closures. It almost seems like your question is determining when a variable is deallocated, not just closures specifically. It not necessary the case that the closure itself is causing the cycle, but what it _captured_ and unable to release is causing the cycle, that being a reference to `self`.